# Malicious web crawler detection

Tags: web-crawler

I would like to know that, is it possible to detect malicious web crawlers in real time by listening to web servers traffic? If it is possible, I would like to know what are the ways to detect bad crawlers.

Comment: How would you differentiate between a good and a "malicious" crawler?

Comment: Is this perhaps a better question for Server Fault?

Comment: Good crawlers are well known crawlers like googlebot, msnbot. I want to detect bogus web crawlers which they do not give anythng in return.